# Counting Lists in Alphabetical Order

Tags: combinatorics

When creating homework for my students, I came up with this:  How many lists of length $5$ can be made from the set
$$
\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I\}
$$
if we cannot repeat a letter and they must be in alphabetical order?

Now, the way I would solve this would be to do a case by case analysis depending on the first letter.  So, start with $A$ and count the lists by choosing a second letter and so on.  Then do the same for $B$ the first letter.  My question is whether there is a much less computationally long answer or an answer that is more instructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $9$ letters. Choose $5$.

Comment: Wow.  My brain does not always go to the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The number of such lists is simply $\binom95$: there’s an obvious bijection between them and $5$-letter subsets of the base set.